# JavaScript check and uncheck checkbox, after uncheck checkbox return to the original state

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm using JavaScript to code a function, that if checkbox is checked disabled the select dropdown, then if uncheck the checkbox and enable the select dropdown.

HTML:

```html
 <input type="checkbox" id="flag">

  <select name="cars" id="select" disabled>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </select>
```

This is how I do it:

```
 function summary()
  {
    if (document.getElementById('flag').checked) 
    {
      document.getElementById('select').disabled = true;
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById('select').disabled = false;
    }
  }
```

My question is, instead of repeating the duplicated code `document.getElementById('select').disabled =`, is there a shorter way to achieve this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could shorten your JS like this by setting one boolean to another.

```js
function summary() {
  document.getElementById('select').disabled = document.getElementById('flag').checked;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write it as follows, since "checked" is a boolean:

```js
function summary() {
  document.getElementById('select').disabled = document.getElementById('flag').checked;
}

document.getElementById("flag").addEventListener("click",summary);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="flag">

<select name="cars" id="select" disabled>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The select menu will be activated when the checkbox is selected and will be inactive when the checkbox is not selected

```js
let flag = document.getElementById('flag');

flag.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('select').disabled = !flag.checked;
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="flag">

<select name="cars" id="select" disabled="true">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
```

The select menu will be inactivated when the checkbox is selected and will be active when the checkbox is not selected

```js
let flag = document.getElementById('flag');

flag.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('select').disabled = flag.checked;
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="flag">

<select name="cars" id="select">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
```